# How can a NestedScrollView with a CollapsingToolbarLayout scroll to an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I've got a layout like the `ScrollingActivity` preset in Android Studio. I've replaced the `TextView` in `content_scrolling` with a `LinearLayout` filled with 20 `EditText` components.

To keep the toolbar on screen when I focus an `EditText`, I've also added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

My problem is that the `NestedScrollView` does not correctly scroll to the focused `EditText`. When the `Toolbar` is not completely collapsed, the `NestedScrollView` does not scroll far enough up. The `Toolbar` does not collapse either.

The obvious solution would be calling `scrollTo` in an `OnFocusChangeListener`, but this does not collapse the `Toolbar`.

How can I make the `NestedScrollView` scroll to the `EditText`, like I would do with my finger?

Comment: There is NestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(), however this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to scroll to a view in a NestedScrollView. This should be executed after the keyboard has been opened.

```
public static void nestedScrollToView(NestedScrollView nestedScrollView, View v, View rootView) {
    nestedScrollView.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
    int[] scrolledBy = new int[2];
    int rootBottom = getBottomOnScreen(rootView);
    int viewBottom = getBottomOnScreen(v);
    int toScrollBy = viewBottom - rootBottom;
    if (toScrollBy > 0) {
        boolean preScrollSuccess = nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, toScrollBy, scrolledBy, null);
        if (preScrollSuccess) {
            boolean scrollSuccess = nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedScroll(0, 0, 0, toScrollBy, null);
        }
        nestedScrollView.scrollBy(0, toScrollBy - scrolledBy[1]);
    }
}

public static int getBottomOnScreen(View view) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    return location[1] + view.getHeight();
}
```